# python- Firestore get() performence issue

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

```
├───Users
│   ├───full_name
│   ├───...
│   ├───connected_groups[]

├───Groups
│   ├───name
│   ├───...
│   ├───connected_users[]
```

`Users` and `Groups` are my collections. Users have `connected_groups` array which holds group reference documents. I need to get details like name, member count etc. of connected groups.

When i use `<DocumentReference>.get().to_dict()` it takes approximately 500ms for each document reference in connected_groups array. So it takes large amount of time to get all of details :(

Then I duplicated data. But groups have `number_of_posts` value. When someone posted a new post, I have to update all users `connected_groups` array in that group. So It will take approximately 25sec to do if there are 50 members in a group.

Are there any way to achieve this?

Update: 
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaOjN.png)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMvQL.png)

nodes=groups in here

Comment: So what is your final goal? What is the expected result?

Comment: My final goal is to get `posts count` in a group. if i use `<DocumentReference>.get().to_dict()` it will take `500ms*no. of connected nodes` of a user.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your database. Is it allowed for you to change the schema?

Comment: @AlexMamo I added. Yes I can change the schema